# Distinguish Physical and Logical network interface using only SNMP?

Tags: networking, snmp

as the title says, how to do that using only SNMP?

given an example like below

[image: Windows SNMPwalk on ifType]
[image: Linux SNMPwalk on ifName ifType and ifSpeed]

as you can see from above example, if I want to determine that only physical interface that has speed, it turn out to be wrong as loopback has speed too.

also I cannot determine that logical interface has "some" ifType value. as the logical interface such as sw0 and vlan1 has the same ifType as it's parents.

so, does anybody have an idea on how to do this? again, using only SNMP?

**EDIT :** why I am being downvoted? if it's really not possible, just say so and explain why? at least there's a reason behind the downvote.

Comment: You can check ifConnectorPresent OID: "This object has the value 'true(1)' if the interface sublayer has a physical connector and the value 'false(2)' otherwise". Another way is to inspect ENTITY-MIB.

Comment: @YuriLachin thank you for telling that, I have check the ifConnectorPresent OID, and all interfaces have a True value, except the loopback, so it cannot be the solution

Comment: You didn't explicitely specify target platform as snmpd on Linux. ifConnectorPresent oid works pretty well for Cisco, Huawei,Juniper routers and switches, but apparently has bad implementation on Linux. Did you compare ifDescr and ifName values for same intefaces? They happen to differ on my debian notebook.